# Tasks: two column under certain condition

Tags: conditionals, tasks

With the help of the `task` package you can produce easily enumerated lists with two or more columns:

- if you write `\begin{tasks}...` everything is printed in *one* column
- if you write `\begin{tasks}(2)...` everything is printed in *two* columns
- if you write `\begin{tasks}(3)...` everything is printed in *three* columns

I want to appear the columns under a certain condition. I tried something like

```
\newtoggle{twocolumn}
\togglefalse{twocolumn}

    % Task 3
    \begin{tasks}\iftoggle{twocolumn}{}{(2)}
    \task one
    \task two
    \task three
    \task four
    \end{tasks}
```

...but this doesn't work!

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

    % Task 1
    \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task one
    \task two
    \task three
    \task four
    \end{tasks}

    % Task 2
    \begin{tasks}
    \task one
    \task two
    \task three
    \task four
    \end{tasks}

\newtoggle{twocolumn}
\togglefalse{twocolumn}

    % Task 3
    \begin{tasks}%\iftoggle{twocolumn}{}{(2)}
    \task one
    \task two
    \task three
    \task four
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `iftoggle` condition to:

```
\begin{tasks}(\iftoggle{twocolumn}{2}{1})
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{twocolumn}
\togglefalse{twocolumn} The toggle is false:

    % Task 3
    \begin{tasks}(\iftoggle{twocolumn}{2}{1}) 
    \task one
    \task two
    \task three
    \task four
    \end{tasks}

\toggletrue{twocolumn} The toggle is true:

  % Task 4
  \begin{tasks}(\iftoggle{twocolumn}{2}{1}) 
      \task one
      \task two
      \task three
      \task four
  \end{tasks}  

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]